# ChangeableText alternative for AndEngine Gles Anchor Center

Tags: android, andengine

Im developing simple game in AndEngine. Now I need to show the time elapse in my game. I could use ChangeableText in Gles2(deprecated) but now Im using AndEngine Anchor Center and it appeared ChangeableText is removed.

There must be some other way to show time elapsed in Anchor Center. 
What is the alternative for CHangeableText so that I can show time elapsed?

Answer (score 0):

You need use Text, it is changeable.

Comment: @Crawler Can you give more information about that exception?